# How do I display my dates?

Tags: java

My code is unable to run successfully and instead this message appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:310)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
    at FuelTransaction.displayDetails(FuelTransaction.java:50)
    at FuelLogger.main(FuelLogger.java:21)
```

**Code**

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FuelLogger
{
    public static void main (String [] arguments)
        {   

            FuelTransaction Ft1 = new FuelTransaction("05/01/2016", 500, 10, 0.990);
            FuelTransaction Ft2 = new FuelTransaction("16/01/2016", 560, 10, 0.990);
            FuelTransaction Ft3 = new FuelTransaction();

            Ft3.setDate("29/01/2016");
            Ft3.setCarMileage(670);
            Ft3.setNumberOfLitres(15);
            Ft3.setCostPerLitre(1.01);

            Ft1.displayDetails();
            Ft2.displayDetails();
            Ft3.displayDetails();

            //allow up to 100 records
            if (FuelTransaction.getTotalNum() > 100)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }

           System.out.println("The total number of FuelTransactions is " + FuelTransaction.getTotalNum());
        }
} 

public class FuelTransaction
{   // properties

    private static int totalNum = 0;
    private String date;
    private int carMileage;
    private int numberOfLitres;
    private double costPerLitre;
    private double cost;

    public FuelTransaction(String inDate, int inCarMileage, int inNumberOfLitres, double inCostPerLitre)
    {
        this.date = inDate;
        this.carMileage = inCarMileage;
        this.numberOfLitres = inNumberOfLitres;
        this.costPerLitre = inCostPerLitre;
        totalNum++;
    }


    public FuelTransaction()
    { 
        totalNum++;
    }

    //methods 

    public void displayDetails()
    {   // display results
        NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        money.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);

        //DateFormat date = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
        DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String inputDate = this.date;
        try
            {
            Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputDate);
            }catch(ParseException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String outputDate = outputFormat.format(date);

    //  System.out.println("Date: " + date.format(this.date));

        System.out.println("CarMileage: " + this.carMileage);
        System.out.println("Number of litres: " + this.numberOfLitres);
        System.out.println("Cost per litre: " + money.format(this.costPerLitre));
        this.displayCost();
    }

    //Date

    public String getDate()
    {
        return this.date;
    }
    public void setDate(String inDate)
    {
        this.date = inDate;
    }

    //Car mileage
    public int getCarMileage()
    {
        return this.carMileage;
    }
    public void setCarMileage(int inCarMileage)
    {
        this.carMileage = inCarMileage;
    }

    //Number of litres
    public int getNumberOfLitres()
    {
        return this.numberOfLitres;
    }
    public void setNumberOfLitres(int inNumberOfLitres)
    {
        this.numberOfLitres = inNumberOfLitres;
    }

    //Cost per litre
    public double getCostPerLitres()
    {
        return this.costPerLitre;
    }
    public void setCostPerLitre(double inCostPerLitre)
    {
        this.costPerLitre = inCostPerLitre;
    }

    //Number of transactions
    public static int getTotalNum()
    {
        return FuelTransaction.totalNum;
    }


    //Calculating

    public void displayCost()
    {
        NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        System.out.println("Cost: " +   money.format(this.cost()));
    }
    private double cost()
    {
        double x = this.numberOfLitres;
        double y = this.costPerLitre;
        x = x * y;
            return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
String outputDate = outputFormat.format(date);
```

You are trying to format a String, when it should be a Date object instead. Since you declared your Date object inside the try block, it is out of scope on the previous line and it uses the String (which shouldn't have the same name to avoid things line this). Change it to:

```
String outputDate = null;
try {
     Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputDate);
     outputDate = outputFormat.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Date: " + outputDate);
```

The thing is, you are not using this `outputDate` for nothing though.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help it worked but now to display the outputDate what must I do?  System.out.println("Date: " + ?);

Comment: Just use `System.out.println("Date: "  + outputDate)` from inside the try block, or define the `outputDate` outside the block, populate it inside and use it wherever you want. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a million I think I'm finally understanding try catch

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here and was not easy to find...:

```
try
   {
       Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputDate);
   }catch(ParseException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   String outputDate = outputFormat.format(date);
```

lets analyse this step by step:

`Date date` object is in the try catch scoped, and **it is totally different as the globally declared** `String date` object (the globally declared String) so your statement:

```
 String outputDate = outputFormat.format(date);
```

is formatting a String because the date object you think you are formatting is not the date object inside the Try-Catch BUT the date:String globally defined...

some people call this a shadow effect, but technically spoken, is just a scope issue...